# Is there any UI Console where I can query the Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Is there any UI Console where I can query the Firebase Database?? Basically I wish to query the data just like we can query other databases using UI

Answer (score 28):

The Firebase Console has built-in support for sorting and filtering the data in a Firestore collection. Click the little filter icon at the top of the collection (next to the overflow menu ).

Many developers also use a local node.js script/REPL (such as in this [video tutorial explaining Firebase Queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVUHx8AQgjg)) or set up a jsfiddle/jsbin (such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38343810)).

Comment: Isn't the web (jsbin) solution a security breach? Using the jsbin logic (web) allows anybody to get the credentials of the firebase db and view the entire database contents.

Comment: The configuration data in the jsbin are just project identifiers: they identify a Firebase project on the Google servers. They are not user credentials, which identify a user. You can share the configuration data, but still mark the database as only accessible to specific users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Currently the firebase console for firestore supports this feature.It supports sorting and applying filters to listing of a collection.

Comment: Good point. I added that.

Answer (score 17):

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, the docs link is currently dead. **This project might be abandoned. Please try the next answer**.

EDIT 2: I removed links to the software and docs since it looked like some phishing website took over the domain.

Original answer:

Check out Firebase Admin. It's a UI for Linux, OSX and Windows and it has a Query tab that lets you experiment with queries.

Read the docs on how to create the private key the app needs to connect to your project.

Comment: is firebase admin trusted ?

Comment: The source is available at https://github.com/codefoxes/firebase-admin - so you can make sure it's safe.

Comment: This app is unstable and doesn't work properly.

Comment: Docs link on this site is dead.

Comment: May 2018 , FireBase Admin latest release is 2016 ... The Docs link is still dead ... Don't loose your time trying to use this app ... It doesn't work.

Comment: Agree with @Fox5150.  I was able to run FireBase Admin and connect, but the app doesn't appear to do anything useful.

Comment: It also seems to the website is under virus

Answer (score 13):

I found and have been using Firestation. Can be used on windows, mac, and linux. I would say to check it out. You can run sql queries against your firebase database.

You can view the source [here](https://github.com/JoeRoddy/firestation).

Comment: Cloud Firestore isn't seems working

Comment: I was able to download and connect using Firestation. However, I didn't  find it very useful.  The features are about the same as Firebase Admin with the addition of sql like queries.

Comment: does not work with Firestore , works fine with realtime db

Comment: Firestore support is in current development, I have just tried it out: https://github.com/JoeRoddy/firestation#firestore

Comment: Firestation don't work for firestore

Comment: Looks like it's no longer in development for Firestore.

Comment: Just saw this new tool - https://firestudio.app/, cant do much but looks like its still new

Comment: This link is also dead